# How can I call JS function while document loading?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a function to dislay menu

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Menu1(id){
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu_' + id).style;
   menu.display = 'block';

} 
</script>
```

and it is call when you move the mouse.

```
<p class="dropdown_link_active" class="active" onmouseover="javascript:Menu1('<?php echo $category['name']; ?>')" >
    <?php echo $category['name'] ?>
</p>
```

I need to display menu while document loading, but not when moving the mouse. Onload is not working.

Comment: Got Any error in console ?

Comment: Attach `onmouseover` event after document loaded ?

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` event will help! Or just call your JS just before closing `<body>` tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with **jQuery**.

Firstly you should define your function

```
function Menu1(id){
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu_' + id).style;
   menu.display = 'block';
}
```

Then you can call that when page was loaded

```
// this meaning as when page loading complete
$(function() {
  // write your function here and call
  Menu1(1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
      Menu1('<?php echo $category['name']; ?>')
    });
</script>
```

This will call your function once, right after the whole document has been loaded.